# shortest way to check if a positive integer is a power of two

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

This question is from job interview...
Use this template to write a C++ function that checks if a positive integer is a power of two.

```
bool p(int n)
{
    return ********;
}
```

You have to replace the 8 '*' symbols with other symbols in order to make the function work correctly.
My best approach was this:

```
bool p(int n)
{
    return !(n&=n-1);
}
```

Unfortunately it was wrong, because there are 9 symbols here...
Any ideas?

Comment: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why assign to `n`? Just remove `=` and you have one character less. It will create a temporary instead, the logic won't change.

Comment: well, I thought '&' had a higher priority than '-'
Thank you!

Comment: Then replace that eight stars with call to the function from the duplicate :)

Comment: @John Devou No, [bitwise AND is below binary minus](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).